# Messaging layout adjust to height of document

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been searching the web for many weeks now, with no result. So I made a jsfiide, here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/2etpk7mw/

What I want to know, is how to make this adjustable with the Window or DOM height? I wrote also a JScript, with no luck! Any help is welcomed. Here's snippets of code:

HTML:

```html
<div id="messagingApp" class="clearfix">
        <div class="usersList">
            <ul>
                <li>Friend</li>
                <li>Friend</li>
                <li>Friend</li>
                <li>Friend</li>
                <li>Friend</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="conversation">
             <ul class="_conversation">
                <li>Recieved</li>
                <li>Sent</li>
                <li>Sent</li>
                <li>Recieved</li>
                <li>Recieved</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="replyBox">Reply from here...</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```css
    body {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #d6d6d6;
        color: #333333;
        font-family: arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        unicode-bidi: embed;
    }

    #messagingApp {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        width: 960px;
    }

    ul {
        list-style: none outside none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .usersList {
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
        float: left;
        height: 600px;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 300px;
    }

    .clearfix:after {
        clear: both;
        content: ".";
        display: block;
        font-size: 0;
        height: 0;
        line-height: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }


    .conversation {
        float: right;
        width: 655px;
    }

    ._conversation > li {
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        height: 50px;
        width: 650px;
    }


    #messagingApp #replyBox {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eee;
        bottom: 0;
        float: right;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        width: 659px;
    }
```

A JScript I wrote:

```jquery
function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(document).height();
    console.log(windowHeight);
    windowHeight = windowHeight;
    console.log(windowHeight); 
}
```

**EDIT: 
Can this all be solved by compatible CSS code, or do I have to apply some jQuery script with Resize event of the browser Window? Thanks in advanced.**

Here's what I want see this illustration/figure:

[image]

Here's an example, any help is appreciated, or url to some tutorial.

[image]

**EDIT: This question will be eligible for bounty tomorrow.**

Comment: You can't just setup a function and that's it. This function has to be called! And for that you can use the resize-event which is fired when the window gets resized...: adding `window.onresize = function () {setHeight()}` should work to call the function, but your function won't work because you aren't doing anything in there except reading out what the height is... **to your edit** Maybe it can be solved using only CSS, but in the case of the height (which will change more often than the width does) you should use Javascript (or even jQuery)

Comment: @Johannes I understand that it has to be called, but what and how shall I modify the heights? I am not sure of which elements height I shall modify. In addition, when scroll in the right-side, the ul li there will populate through Ajax calls. Meaning, the layout shouldn't break, it shall stay the same, the content inside shall change and a scroll bar shall work things out, I am not sure of how this is done correctly with JScript or jQuery, any help or modification of the jsfiddle I posted is welcomed.

Comment: So you want to have the whole window filled out and then there will be a scrollbar if you have more content than you can show on the screen? - Why you don't want to show it in the normal window (body-tag) and the scrollbars will appear 'on their own'? Have a look at @sikado's answer and try it out.

Comment: @Johannes I am trying something, will report you back!

Comment: @Johannes Nope, I am unable to fix anything. Any help and guidance is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm no sure if I fully understand what you want to achieve but I don't have enough reputation to make a comment)

As I understand, you want `#messagingApp` to have the same height as the window.

### Using CSS

In CSS, `height: 100%` is the height of the parent element. But, by default, the body will have the size of its content and not of the window. To fix that you need to do:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
```

[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2etpk7mw/1/)

### Using JQuery

If, for some reason, you want to use JS rather than CSS, you can use the following.

```
$("#messagingApp").height($( window ).height());
```

As @Johannes said, you need to change the height of `#messagingApp` each time the user is resizing the window. So, you need to add also:

```
$(window).on("resize", function(){
    $("#messagingApp").height($( window ).height());
});
```

[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2etpk7mw/2/)

Comment: See my image I uploaded

Comment: I don't get what you want. In both JsFiddle of my answer the main `div` is always taking the whole height of the window

Comment: Do you see the screenshot I posted?

Comment: This fiddle works for me, don't know whether it's what @JohnSmith searches for. But we don't have to write for you the code you want. All we can say is that you can do that with jQuery and you got the start from sikado. Of course you have to experiment a lot if you aren't used to create something like this, but you will gain experience...